# "Something that is used to ..." - Is it a correct noun phrase?

Tags: grammaticality, noun-phrases

I have a technical document where I want to give a section a name "Parentheses to make operator precedence explicit". But I am not sure whether it is grammatically correct.

I don't like the second version because it's somewhat wordy, but in the same time I'm not sure whether the first one is correct.

> #### Parentheses to make operator precedence explicit
>
> It is better to not omit them.
>
> ```
> (2 * 3) - 1   // Do
> ```
>
> ```
> 2 * 3 - 1     // Don't
> ```

> #### Parentheses that are used to make operator precedence explicit
>
> ...

Comment: A header doesn't really need to be "grammatically correct", because it's not a sentence. For a technical document, you should follow general guidelines of similar documents on how your headers should be structured -- i.e. starting with verbs, use of proper nouns, use of complete sentence etc. etc. ... With that being said, I think the 1st header is more direct and less confusing. You may also try "Parentheses Make Operator Precedence Explicit", which is both succinct and a complete sentence

Comment: As the comment above makes clear, titles and captions need not be sentences. But it is best to make them as pertinent as possible. This is **advice**. So say. "Recommendation to make precedence explicit." Then in addition to what you say, you can justify it. "We recommend using parentheses to make precedence of operations explicit because ... For example, ..."